# what's the diff: WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR v.s. WS_VSCROLL&VS_HSCROLL

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi

see the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WS_VSCROLL will decide if vertical scroll will be present in window or not. - 1
WS_HSCROLL will decide if horizontal scroll will be present in window or not.

WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR will make the  vertical scroll bar(if present, decided by 1) appear to the right.
WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR will make the vertical scroll bar(if present, decided by 1) appear to the left.